# Calculate the percentage of missing values per month in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I create the following dataframe:

```
    df <- data.frame(seq(from = as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2001-12-31"), by = 1),
                     seq(1,365), seq(1, 365), seq(1, 365), seq(1, 365))
    colnames(df) <- c("date", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4")
    df$C1[50:100] <- NA
    df$C2[20:80] <- NA
    df$C3[70:150] <- NA
    df$C4[250:300] <- NA
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of missing values per month, not just per column but for the whole dataset.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(lubridate)

#is.na(.) can be more specific e.g. is.na(.[,2:5]) OR is.na(.[,grepl("C",colnames(df))])

 df %>% mutate(Month=month(date), Mis = rowSums(is.na(.))) %>% 
        group_by(Month) %>% 
        summarise(Sum=sum(Mis), Percentage=mean(Mis))
```